# I need to create a temporary key in Azure to use in Terraform

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am using Terraform cloud and I don't want to use permanent keys in it. So, is there any to create a temporary keys in Azure Cloud(like we can create in AWS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are [authenticating to Azure Cloud via Azure service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/get-started-cloud-shell#authenticate-via-azure-service-principal), by default, the Az CLI command will get a password for this service principal with a one-year expiration date.

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --role="Contributor" --scopes="/subscriptions/<subscription_id>"
```

from your comments, in fact you want to get this password to expire in a short time. You can use `az ad app credential reset` to append or overwrite an application's password or certificate credentials.

For example, reset the application password with the following Az CLI commands.

```
az ad app credential reset --id <appId> --password <sp_password> --end-date 2020-08-13T11:59:59+00:00
```

[image]

For more information, you could read the [Relationship between application objects and service principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals#relationship-between-application-objects-and-service-principals)

Comment: As I see in portal we can give expiry only 1 year or 2 year. Is it possible to short the time to 4-5 Hrs through this command?

And can you please explain me why you have used change password and end-date both in a single command?

Comment: You can only shorten the time with commands, not UI. Have you tried the `az ad app credential reset `command that passes the old existing password but reset the end data in one command? Is it working for you?

Comment: Do you have more questions?

Answer (score 0):

By creating a [**ServicePrincipal**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/serviceprincipal?view=graph-rest-1.0) in AzureAD you're also able to [assign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-tokenlifetimepolicies?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) a **LifetimePolicy** ([tokenLifetimePolicies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/tokenlifetimepolicy?view=graph-rest-1.0)). This way you're able to have an "end of life" for the token.

Here's also a short [how to on creating a new ServicePrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal).

---

Alternatevily you could use this new preview feature: [Configurable token lifetimes in Microsoft identity platform (Preview).](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes)

As it is a preview feature you're not supposed to use it in production environments.

Comment: What I notice is in Azure to authenticate Terraform we use subscription_id and tennant_id. I want to automate the process through cli. Can you please help me to create a temporary tennant_id(or keys) through the CLI and that key I can pass it to Terraform cloud. And key should expire in like 4-5hrs.